# Why aren't the correct images being pulled from the folder when I try to animate the player character?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've heard posting huge blocks of text is a big no no here, so I'll try to only show the parts where I think the problem could be. However, if anyone wants to see more of my code, I will happily provide it. This is done in C# winforms, and I know there are better things to use than C# winforms for game creation, but this is for a school project and it is required to be in winforms.

```
private void SetUp()
{
    //Player character files loaded into the list
    this.DoubleBuffered = true;

    playerMovements = Directory.GetFiles("knightimages", "*.png").ToList();
    
    foreach (var filePath in playerMovements)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Loaded file: {filePath}");
    }
    knight = Image.FromFile(playerMovements[0]);
}
```

This is the method I'm using to put all the images to animate the character into the "playerMovements" list. My program accesses these images and displays the knight character.

```
private void AnimateKnight(int start, int end)
{
    slowFrameRate += 1;

    if (slowFrameRate == 4)
    {
        steps++;
        slowFrameRate = 0;

        if (steps > end || steps < start)
        {
            steps = start;
        }

        knight = Image.FromFile(playerMovements[steps]);
    }
}
```

This is the method used to animate the knight. I'm not sure if the problem is here, but I'm including it anyway because the issue is that he doesn't animate quite right.

```
private void TimerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Core.IsLeft && playerX > 0)
    {
        playerX -= playerSpeed;
        //AnimateKnight(8, 11);
    }
    if (Core.IsRight && playerX + playerWidth < this.ClientSize.Width)
    {
        playerX += playerSpeed;
        AnimateKnight(12,15);
    }
    this.Invalidate();
}
```

This is my timer event. I think the issue might be in here? The problem is, that the images I'm wanting it to use (Images 8 through 11 for left, and 12 through 15 for right) aren't being used. Instead, the program seems to almost run through all of the images in the folder whenever the knight character moves. And he moves just fine, it's just the animation that's not right.

I have ensured that all of the images are named correctly and placed in the right order. But it still is pulling the wrong images. I've been trying to figure out what's wrong, and done a little debugging (which I'm very new at) and I still can't find the issue. Please help! As previously stated, if anyone wants to see all of the code, I will happily provide it.

Also, I followed this video tutorial, and even though as far as I can tell my code matches his, it's not working like his is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaoczTCHAwc

I only have him moving left and right currently. This is because I was just testing those two directions. He'll eventually move up and down too. And left is commented out because I was just testing the right for now.

I have tried changing the numbers in the TimerEvent AnimateKnight(), and I have tried to do some debugging with console.writeline, in both the AnimateKnight method and the SetUp method.

The console.writeline in AnimateKnight method showed that it was working correctly (I think) and the writeline in SetUp showed that is was loading images in the folder that I had not told it to. What I mean is, when the character moved right, images 12-15 should have been used and animated. Instead, it was using images 0-8?? I have no idea why it's doing this.

Comment: @IV. I'm so sorry, but I am very new to this kind of this. This program is for a school project. So... where do I find the declaration of the timer? I added the timer from the toolbox and added the handler by going to the Tick behavior and typing TimerEvent. I'm sorry if that doesn't make sense

Comment: Tells me just what I need to know! Thanks. _Oh, but what's the interval set to?_

Comment: @IV. Oh, good. It's set to 20!

Comment: @IV. I made it both super fast and super slow, and it is the same issue. It seems to be pulling the wrong Images from the folder, even though I've told it which images to use. It just continues using some of the other images, if that makes sense. I've told it to use images 12-15 if the character goes right, but instead it's using images 6-9

Comment: I think you're assuming the files are coming out in a different order than they really are, and yet you're just using the raw index.

Comment: Oh here we go. Even better: Do this please:

`playerMovements = Directory
                .GetFiles(ImageFolder, "*.png");

            for(int i=0; i<playerMovements.Length; i++)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Index {i} - {Path.GetFileName(playerMovements[i])}");
            }`

Comment: It might be as simple as doing a sort on that list of file names to line up the index properly.

Comment: @IV. Hmm, that turned the animation into a still image, even though according to the output, it was still using multiple images. The wrong images, but it was using multiple of them. How would I do a sort?

Comment: @IV. Oh, I only did the second thing since you said that was better to try

Comment: give me a second and I'll post a real answer it's difficult in the text. in the meantime, just put your code back to where it works. I'll explain better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our conversation in comments, I have a suspicion that the `playerMovements` list that you constructed using `Directory.GetFiles("knightimages", "*.png").ToList();` is not in the order that you think it is. As a result, referencing it by index gives an unexpected result.

A common mistake is to index images without padding, like image.0.png, image.2.png ... image.10.png, image.11.png. But look what can happen.

```
playerMovements = Directory
    .GetFiles(ImageFolder, "*.png");

for(int i=0; i<playerMovements.Length; i++)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Index {i} - {Path.GetFileName(playerMovements[i])}");
}
```

[image: index does not match file]

You think they'd be in order, but they're not. They're sorted (by default in alphanumeric sequence that sees the number value differently than we do.

All signs point to something like this is occurring. So what I meant in the comment was to "print out" the names of the files in your image directory so we can understand the order that they're really in.

---

Pasting the snippet in shouldn't have any effect on the animation, but regardless, it just needs to exist long enough to get this printout into the Debug console, then you can take it right back out again.

Just insert that snippet right after you read the `Directory.Files` in, and set a breakpoint right after this loop, and look at the list that gets printed out. (should look something like the image I posted)

Comment: This was very helpful! And you're right, they're not in the right order. When I put in that code, the output looked like this.
`Index 0 - Knight10.png
Index 1 - Knight11.png
Index 2 - Knight12.png
Index 3 - Knight13.png
Index 4 - Knight14.png
Index 5 - Knight15.png
Index 6 - Knight_00.png
Index 7 - Knight_01.png
Index 8 - Knight_02.png
Index 9 - Knight_03.png
Index 10 - Knight_04.png
Index 11 - Knight_05.png
Index 12 - Knight_06.png
Index 13 - Knight_07.png
Index 14 - Knight_08.png
Index 15 - Knight_09.png`
How would I fix that? Or work with it?

Comment: The easiest thing would be to remove the underscore characters from_00 thru _09. Does changing file names fall within the constraints of your school project? (Because your job might be to figure out how to sort them and I don't want to ruin your fun!)

Comment: Oh my gosh, that's all it was! The file names were not consistent! I can't believe that's all it was. I've been working on this all day. Thank you so much for helping me. I don't think I ever would have figured it out on my own! I didn't even realize the image names were inconsistent!

Comment: I clicked the checkmark and upvoted! Thank you again so much!